# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 error in my java program

Tags: java

I seem to get an error when I test running my program, which says java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Please can anyone give me some advice on how to fix this?

```
class MineFinderModel {
public static int MINE_SQUARE = 10;
public static int EMPTY_SQUARE = 0;

int num_of_cols;
int num_of_rows;
int[][] the_minefield;

public MineFinderModel(int n_cols, int n_rows) {
    num_of_rows = n_rows;
    num_of_cols = n_cols;
    the_minefield = new int[num_of_cols][num_of_rows];
}

public boolean addMine(int thisCol, int thisRow) {
    if (thisCol >= num_of_cols || thisRow >= num_of_rows)
        return false;
    if (the_minefield[thisCol][thisRow] == MINE_SQUARE)
        return false;
    the_minefield[thisCol][thisRow] = MINE_SQUARE;
    return true;
}

public int getValue(int thisCol, int thisRow) {
    if (thisCol >= num_of_cols || thisRow >= num_of_rows)
        return 0;
    return the_minefield[thisCol][thisRow];
}

public void addMinesToCorners() {
    the_minefield[0][0] = MINE_SQUARE;
    the_minefield[0][num_of_rows -1] = MINE_SQUARE;
    the_minefield[num_of_cols - 1][0] = MINE_SQUARE;
    the_minefield[num_of_cols - 1][num_of_rows - 1] = MINE_SQUARE;
}
```

}

Comment: on what line do you get the exception ?

Comment: Obviously one of your functions that do array manipulation (that's all of them) has an arithmetic error. A stack trace would help narrowing it down.

Comment: what line, and if it's inside your `addMine` and `getValue` methods, we need to see the code that invokes those methods

Comment: you didn't post enough of the program for us to know what it tried to do.

Comment: when i test for the mines inside/outside the field, it provides this error.

Comment: does anyone fancy dropping me an email, as got a few things to ask? morrismatty@ymail.com

Comment: @MatthewMorris no, nobody wants to enter email correspondence with you.  if you have clarifications to make, you can make them here.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that it should be in the "addMinesToCorners()" function since you are not testing the boundaries.
What about trying to put some if around you variables ?

```
if(num_of_cols == 0)
if(num_of_rows == 0)
```

At initialization, this equals "0", and then "0 - 1" gives "-1". Hence the error.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are zero indexed so your checks are incorrect, e.g., if num_of_cols is 10 then the last position will be 9 but your check will pass if you pass in 10 as thisCol because it is checking against the initialiser value instead of the length of the array. 
Try changing your test to

```
if (thisCol < 0  thisCol >= (num_of_cols - 1) || thisRow < 0 || thisRow >= num_of_rows - 1))
```

Comment: again, he returns when the condition evaluates to true.

Comment: no Sam, he is returning false if the mine couldn't be added. If EITHER of those conditions are met then returning false is correct. Maybe you should read the code properly before down voting. Although he should check for negative values as Amit said.

Comment: I did read the code, and I can tell you right now that your condition WILL cause out of range exceptions in ways that the OP's will not.

Answer (score 0):

All your methods have the max value check but none of them are checking for a negative value in thisRow and thisCol so the addMine() and getValue() will throw an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if any of the arguments to these 2 methods is negative.
You can add a condition like 
`

```
if (thisCol >= num_of_cols || thisCol < 0
            || thisRow >= num_of_rows || thisRow <0)

 return false
```